# ORA-06550 Procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: oracle

Create a function named 'find_company' which accepts a character and displays company name starts with the given character input using cursors.
Hints:
Procedure name: find_company
Input parameter : alpha with data type as varchar
Output parameter : company_name with data type as varchar
Design rules: 1) If the character (i.e, alpha) passed as input,  matches then it returns the company name.
2) If the character (i.e, alpha) passed as input, does not match ,then use 'cursorname%notfound' to return the company_name with the text as 'No Such Companies with the given Character'.

I coded as below

```
create or replace procedure find_company (alpha IN varchar2)
AS
cursor test_cur(alpha IN VARCHAR2)
 IS
 select name from company where name like alpha||'%';
 ret _company_name company.name%TYPE;
begin
 OPEN test_cur(alpha);
 LOOP
 FETCH test_cur into ret_company_name;
   dbms_output.put_line(ret_company_name);
   EXIT WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND THEN ret_company_name:='No Such Companies with the given Character';
 close test_cur;
end;
/
```

Getting following error:
Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.
d := find_company('C');
*
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 9:
PLS-00905: object P10456.FIND_COMPANY is invalid
ORA-06550: line 7, column 4:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Where am I doing wrong ? I do not have option to use 'show errors' command

Comment: Off the top of my head, there is no `end loop`, you can't have a `then` on an `exit when` statement.

Comment: What if multiple company name matches the input? What is needed in output? Varchar or cursor or UDT?

Comment: To answer ORA_Dentist - Output parameter : company_name with data type as varchar

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code as follows but still getting issues -

```
create or replace procedure find_company (alpha IN varchar2, ret _company_name OUT varchar2)
AS
cursor test_cur
 IS
 select name from company where name like alpha||'%';
 ret _company_name company.name%TYPE;
begin
 OPEN test_cur(alpha);
 LOOP
 FETCH test_cur into ret_company_name;
   dbms_output.put_line(ret_company_name);
   exit WHEN test_cur%NOTFOUND THEN ret_company_name:='No Such Companies with the given Character';
 end loop;
 close test_cur;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION find_company(alpha IN VARCHAR) RETURN VARCHAR
    IS
    company_name VARCHAR (50);
        CURSOR c1 IS
        SELECT name
        FROM Company
        WHERE substr(name,0,1) =alpha;
        BEGIN
           OPEN c1;
           LOOP
           FETCH c1 into company_name;
           EXIT;
           END LOOP;
           
           IF c1%notfound THEN
              company_name :='No Such Companies with the given Character';
          END IF;
          CLOSE c1;
           RETURN company_name;
        END;
    /
```

Comment: A little more context on what has been done / change and why could be good to know